# Shopware 6 empty theme

Tags: php, woocommerce, shopware, shopware6

I am currently exploring Shopware 6. I come from WooCommerce so i have a hard time understanding everything.

For what i understand, with a custom theme, you always inherit from the normal Shopware theme?

I wanted to create entirely empty theme with nothing, but that is just not possible i guess? I am stuck with the Shopware styling loading in my page? Even if i want to make an entire other design?

Can somebody explain me this a bit better? As i said, i come from WooCommerce, so i am used to a parent theme being something you can just empty out if it is your own and not receiving updates.

Answer (score 1):

> For what i understand, with a custom theme, you always inherit from the normal Shopware theme?

```json
{
  "name": "SwagBasicExampleTheme",
  "author": "Shopware AG",
  "views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@Plugins",
     "@SwagBasicExampleTheme"
  ],
  "style": [
    "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss",
    "@Storefront",
    "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"
  ],
  "script": [
    "@Storefront",
    "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/swag-basic-example-theme.js"
  ],
  "asset": [
    "@Storefront",
    "app/storefront/src/assets"
  ],
  "configInheritance": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@OtherTheme"
    ]
}
```

This is an example theme configuration, Shopware recommends building on the default theme (Storefront) but you can decide by yourself. For example, if you do not want inherit styling from the default shopware theme, you can remove `@Storefront` from `style`, and do the same for javascript or views...

You can get more details from the document https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration

> I wanted to create entirely empty theme with nothing, but that is just not possible i guess? I am stuck with the Shopware styling loading in my page? Even if i want to make an entire other design?

It's possible. As above explained.

> Can somebody explain me this a bit better? As i said, i come from WooCommerce, so i am used to a parent theme being something you can just empty out if it is your own and not receiving updates.

Shopware also has the same. You can create a child theme from an existing theme. This is document https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/add-theme-inheritance#extending-an-existing-theme-with-a-new-theme

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I removed everything i did not want from the theme.json file. I am now getting an error if i visit my shop `Unable to load template "storefront/base.html.twig". (Looked into: Framework, Profiling, Administration, Elasticsearch) in "@Storefront/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig"`

If i removed everything, why is @Storefront still being loaded?

Comment: did you have template `storefront/base.html.twig` in your theme?

Comment: Not that i know of... its just an empty theme.